# Some problems on QUIC-GO example server

Tags: go, server, quic

The situation is, I wanna establish a QUIC connection based on quic-go from local to ECS server. The related tests using *localhost* are done both on local and remote device. That is:

`#local: .$QUIC-GO-PATH/example/client/main -insecure -keylog ssl.log -qlog trial.log -v https://127.0.0.1:6121/demo/tile`

`#local: .$QUIC-GO-PATH/example/main -qlog -tcp -v`

These tests are completed.

Now is the problem,when I start local-remote connection an error occurred:

`#remote: .$QUIC-GO-PATH/example/main -qlog -tcp -v`

`#local: .$QUIC-GO-PATH/example/client/main -insecure -keylog ssl.log -qlog trial.log -v https://$REMOTE_IPADDR:6121/demo/tile`

[timeout: no recent network activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luNKy.png)

When I go through a wireshark examination, it seems like the CRYPTO handshake never finishes:

[Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XT1i.png)

Also client Qlog file atteched here:

[Qlog file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE5Pn.png)

Codes are all the same with https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved.

Code $QUIC-GO-PATH/example/main.go has binded the port as a default onto 127.0.0.1:6121, which led to the problem that the server cannot get reached by client outside, just get this on server running:

`-bind 0.0.0.0:6121`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.